# vba only add new series to the chart if it does not exist

Tags: vba, excel

I have several sheets in my workbook which contains data to plot, every time I run a new analysis a new sheet is generated.

On my first sheet I plot all the data in the same graph, so to avoid re plotting all the series every time I append a new sheet I would like to just add a new series.

[image]

I thought that should be simple, but it is not for two reasons: When I first create the chart it adds somewhere between 1 and 9 series automatically:

```
 Set myChart = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
 myChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
```

why does this generate any random series?

also if I delete the graph because I want to rerun one analysis, the graph will then be called 2 and so on...  So I tried to give it a name and refer to its name instead, however that does not work:

```
Set myChart = ws.ChartObjects(ws.Name)
```

So in the first sheet(Orginal) I plot all data in the workbook, and in the rest I just plot the data for the current sheet as seen below. I use the same code function for both cases, where i just pass the argument all as true(orginal sheet) or false(sheet 1.....300)

[image]

Below is the code:

```
Sub createChart(ws As Worksheet, Optional all As Boolean = False)
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim temp As Integer
Dim n As Integer


On Error Resume Next
' Delete the charts, just in case
If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then ' And Not all Then
    ws.ChartObjects.Delete
End If

'If ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
    Set myChart = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    myChart.Name = ws.Name
'Else
    'Set myChart = ws.ChartObjects(ws.Name) '''Fails why commented out
'End If



myChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
myChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMinor)
myChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMinorMajor)
myChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
myChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)

myChart.Parent.width = 800  ' px width graph
myChart.Parent.height = 500 ' px height graph

' it adds mysterious sometimes several random series, so we need to delete those that does not match sheet name
For n = myChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 0 Step -1
    If Not SheetExists(myChart.SeriesCollection(n).Name) Then
        myChart.SeriesCollection(n).Delete
    End If
Next n


'*******************************************************************
'**************** FIRST PAGE CHART *********************************
'*******************************************************************
If all Then
    Dim wsOther As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fixRange As Boolean
    Dim skipGraph As Boolean

    fixRange = True

    myChart.HasLegend = True
    myChart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight
    myChart.Parent.Top = 120
    myChart.Parent.Left = 450


    For Each wsOther In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsOther.Name <> ws.Name Then
            lastRow = getLastRow(wsOther, 1)
            skipGraph = False
            '******* we only add graphs if it is not before ******************
            If myChart.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then
                For n = myChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If myChart.SeriesCollection(n).Name = wsOther.Name Then
                        skipGraph = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next n
            End If

            If Not skipGraph Then
                With myChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .Values = "=" & wsOther.Name & "!$E$2:$E$" & lastRow
                    .Name = wsOther.Name
                    .XValues = "=" & wsOther.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & lastRow
                End With
           End If
            If fixRange Then
                ' Range on axis
                myChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MinimumScale = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(wsOther.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & lastRow).Value2))
                myChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MaximumScale = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(wsOther.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & lastRow).Value2))

                myChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
                fixRange = False
            End If

        End If
    Next


'*******************************************************************************************************
'****************** SINGLE CHART ***********************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************************************
Else
    myChart.HasLegend = False
    myChart.Parent.Top = 40
    myChart.Parent.Left = 300


    lastRow = getLastRow(ws, 1)

    With myChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!$E$2:$E$" & lastRow
        .XValues = "=" & ws.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & lastRow
    End With

    ' Range on axis
    myChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MinimumScale = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(ws.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & lastRow).Value2))
    myChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MaximumScale = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(ws.Name & "!$B$2:$B$" & lastRow).Value2))
End If

' *********************************************************************
' ******************* Sizing ******************************************
' *********************************************************************

With myChart.PlotArea
    temp = .Top
    temp = .height
    .Top = 70
    .height = 420
End With

'really dirty and crappy formatting of title
myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Faraday Torr"

'X axis name
myChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
myChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time [s]"


'y-axis name
myChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
myChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Pressure[Torr]"




Set myChart = Nothing
Set wsOther = Nothing

ws.Select
ws.Range("A1").Select



End Sub
```

Comment: Please read about creating [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you clarify your question/what you are trying to achieve? I am struggling to understand your question. Are you wanting to loop sheets adding the data in them as new series to your "master chart" only if not already found?  Also, is all that code necessary?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I tried to clarify the problems better now, the code works, its just so slow when I have to replot every series every time a new series is added, instead of just adding it to existing plot

Comment: How is your data laid out in each new sheet so one can understand how that data can be pulled into a chart? It sounds like you may want to loop all sheets, populate a table from that and have an associated pivotchart or a dynamic range based chart. You could empty and re-populate the table each time you run an experiment. Might not be the most efficient way. Depends if there is a reliable way to identify sheets with experiments you want to remove/include again (struggling a little to visualize that bit of the process at the moment).

Comment: Each sheet just have 5 columns where I use column B for x axis and E for y axis, wouldnt  empty and re-populate the table each time you run an experiment be very time consuminng when we have 100+ sheets with 1000+ rows?